# Ubuntu unbootable after upgrade from 21.04 to 21.10

Tags: upgrade, 21.10

I did the usual system upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo update-manager -c
```

Accepted all the defaults and now my computer boots into emergency mode. When I type `exit` or `systemctl default` I get an error `failed to start default target transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive`. My computer is completely unbootable right now.
I tried fixing my partitions

```
fsck /dev/sdb2 (my boot partition)
fsck /dev/sdb4 (my filesystem partition)
```

but it didn't help.
I also tried updating my `grub`

```
update-grub
```

but that didn't help either.

I cannot install any package from the internet because I have no internet connection in emergency mode. I am stuck.
Why is my system completely broken after system upgrade and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I looked into last boot logs:

```
journalctl -b
```

and found that the system had issues mounting one of my `ntfs` drives. I don't know why, though. It was previously mounted this way:

```
# /etc/fstab
UUID=96C8335EC8333BB5      /mnt/fun        ntfs    defaults     0       0
```

I commented this line and, to my surprise, my system booted up just fine.
I then tried to uncomment this line and remount it

```
sudo mount -a
```

but I got an error:

```
unknown filesystem type 'nfts'
```

Strange because it used to work fine before the upgrade. I looked it up in Google and found this article that demonstrates how to mount an 'ntfs' partition on linux. https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-mount-a-windows-ntfs-disk-in-linux/
It says to install `ntfs-3g` package which happened to be already installed . Then, mount the partition this way:

```
UUID=96C8335EC8333BB5      /mnt/fun        ntfs-3g    defaults     0       0
```

```
sudo mount -a
```

Restart the system and voila!
I hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late for you, but I just helped a friend with this same issue. The solution was simple. It has to do with a disk not being able to be mounted.

In my friend's case, in the /etc/fstab file, there was an extra entry for an external USB hard drive. For some reason, the system wasn't able to find it at boot, and it caused this same draconian message that you're getting.

The solution was simply to edit the file (`sudo nano /etc/fstab`) and put a # at the start of the relevant line to prevent the line from being active. Reboot and computer started up normally.

This whole thing happened when updating Kubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.